# Unable to add multiple categories to a post in Wordpress

Tags: categories

I have just created a page and it is live.

I currently have `Freehand` as the one category for the page.

However if I then select

- Freehand
- Pledge Video
- How To

and then click update, it will notify me that the page has successfully updated. The page will update its `state` and only `Freehand` will be selected.

[image]

I do have plugins:

```
Plugin  Description
Advanced Product Search For WooCommerce
Advanced Product Wishlist for Woocomerce
Akismet Anti-Spam
Customer Reviews for WooCommerce
Elementor
EnvoThemes Demo Import
Genesis Layout Extras
Hello Dolly
Image optimisation service by Optimole
Jetpack by WordPress.com
Mailchimp for WooCommerce
One Click Demo Import
Orbit Fox Companion
PayPal PLUS for WooCommerce
Polylang
PowerPack Lite for Elementor
s2Member Framework
Smart Variation Swatches for WooCommerce
Toolbar Extras
WooCommerce
WooCommerce Admin
Woocommerce Events Manager
WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Gateway
WooCommerce Popup Cart + ajax
WooCommerce Services
WooCommerce Subscriptions
WPForms Lite
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the classic debugging process?
(It is better to perform these operations on a local environment rather than on the production environment)

1. Make a full backup of your website
2. Try to disable the plugin one by one and see if the bug disappears.
3. Try to change the theme

You can then identify if the bug comes from a plugin or your theme.